# Still visible soft keyboard

Tags: android, vimeo, soft-keyboard

I have curious case of still visible soft-keyboard.
Simple flow.
Activity without any edittexts, where soft keyboard is hidden.
From manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

...and also checked from code

```
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

In this activity I have a fragment which contains webview. I have added touchlistener to this webview which send 'space' key to it.

```
protected View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
                inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE);
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

It handles start/pause effect, where I have vimeo video-content of that webview. Previously I tried to communicate with vimeo video player by javascript handler, but it wasn't work. Sending key event is really simple  solution and works great on all devices except one. On dell t01c when touchlistener is invoked, software keyboard appears. I can hide it with simple

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

but it ruins immersive mode of activity - navigation bar shows and disappears. How to block keyboard permanently? Has anyone had similar problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

put this static method in your Utils class

```
 public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
            try {
                InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager) activity
                        .getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                input.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Call this method whereever you want to hide the keyboard by Utils.hideKeyboard(YOURACTIVITY.this);

Comment: Have you read question to the end? I wrote that, this solution is ruining immersive mode.